# Android Game Slows Down

Tags: android, graphics, eclipse

I had been developing a **Maze Game** which is dragging a bitmap down on the maze going on the finish line. on first my game response quickly on my onTouch and dragging and after couples of
**adding toast message, generate random mazes, changing character from drawCircle into a bitmap and a background from a solid color into a customize PNG file** my game seems to **Slows Down**.

Can anyone explain why could this happen?

And what should I do to make my game to response more quickly?

Tnx for the help and godbless.

**UPDATE**: I found out that it all started when i change my solid color background to a bitmap background.

here's my code:

From this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);
```

To this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu_bg);
//Set Rectangle Size and Coordinates
RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,width,height);
//Maze with Background
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
```

Comment: Are you releasing resources properly? Especially bitmaps are susceptible to that.

Comment: What do you mean by releasing resources properly? my bitmaps are only the character and the background. and all my levels have same backgrounds.

Comment: @icecream do you call BitmapFactory.decodeResource each time you render your game?

Comment: sir @AlphSpirit I call it on my onDraw method. Am I doing right? Actually it gives me no error but it delays my ontouch event.

Comment: @icecream If you could tell us which engine or library you use, I could complete my answer.

Comment: @AlphSpirit appcompat_v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of the major reason your code is slow is because you load your bitmap every time you render your game. Try putting this line in an initialization function:

```
...
Bitmap bitmap;

protected void init() {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu_bg);
}

...

protected void onDraw() {
    //Set Rectangle Size and Coordinates
    RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,width,height);
    //Maze with Background
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
}
```

If you could post your entire code, I could tell you exactly where to put this line, but your engine should have something like a constructor or an init() function.

Comment: I already figured it out. thanks to you sir. thanks for the help logic and time :)